# How to handle HTML Radio Buttons with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Algebra Reviewer </title>
<style type="text/css">
h2
{
color: white;
font-family: verdana;
text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
text-align: center;
}
table
{
font-family:verdana;
color: white;
text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function question1()
{
if ("quiz.question1.value=='d'")
{
alert ("That's the correct answer!");
} 
else
{
alert ("Oops! try again!");
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</br>
<h2>
Here are 10 items for you to answer. You might need scratch paper- so get one before taking this reviewer.
</h2>
</br>
</br>
<center>
<table border="0" bgcolor="tan">
<tr> <td>
<ol>
<li> What is the equation of the line passing through point (3,8) and parallel to the line x - 3y = 5 ? </li>
</br>
</br> 
<input type = "radio" name = "question1" onclick = "quiz.question1.value=='a'"/> y = 1/3 x + 5
</br>
<input type = "radio" name = "question1" onclick = "quiz.question1.value=='b'"/> y = 3x + 7
</br>
<input type = "radio" name = "question1" onclick = "quiz.question1.value=='c'"/> y = 3/5 x + 3
</br>
<input type = "radio" name = "question1" onclick = "quiz.question1.value=='d'"/> y = 1/3 x + 7
</br>
</br>
<input type = "button" onclick = "question1()" name = "question1" value = "Submit"/>
<br/>
<br/>
</td> </tr> </table> </center>
</body>
</html
```

The answer here should be the 4th radio button, but I think that the `if / else` statement is wrong.

Comment: Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org) and stop using tables for laout.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: Totally unrelated, but I think the server should validate the correct answer instead of javascript. If you don't do that your students will easily cheat looking in the source html code for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, set the radios `value` attribute as the options. modify the following in your html

```
<input type = "radio" name = "question1" value='a'/> y = 1/3 x + 5
</br>
<input type = "radio" name = "question1" value='b'/> y = 3x + 7
</br>
<input type = "radio" name = "question1" value='c'/> y = 3/5 x + 3
</br>
<input type = "radio" name = "question1" value='d'/> y = 1/3 x + 7
```

and change the function as follows:

```
function question1()
{
  var selectedAns;
  var questions = document.getElementsByName("question1");
  for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
     if(questions[i].checked == true) {
     selectedAns = questions[i].value;
     break;
  }

  if(selectedAns== 'd')
    alert ("That's the correct answer!");
  } 
  else
  {
   alert ("Oops! try again!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never defined the quiz variable. Use value attribute to get selected radio button. Use the following code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Algebra Reviewer </title>
<style type="text/css">
h2 {
   color: white;
   font-family: verdana;
   text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
   text-align: center;
}
table {
   font-family:verdana;
   color: white;
   text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function question1() {
       var option = document.querySelector('input[name = "question1"]:checked').value;
       if (option == 'd') {
          alert("That's the correct answer!");
       } 
       else {
          alert ("Oops! try again!");
       }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</br>
<h2>
Here are 10 items for you to answer. You might need scratch paper- so get one before taking this reviewer.
</h2>
</br>
</br>
<center>
<table border="0" bgcolor="tan">
   <tr> 
     <td>
        <ol>
           <li> What is the equation of the line passing through point (3,8) and parallel to the line x - 3y = 5 ? </li>
           </br>
           </br> 
           <input type = "radio" name = "question1" value="a" /> y = 1/3 x + 5
           </br>
           <input type = "radio" name = "question1" value="b" /> y = 3x + 7
           </br>
           <input type = "radio" name = "question1" value="c" /> y = 3/5 x + 3
           </br>
           <input type = "radio" name = "question1" value="d" /> y = 1/3 x + 7
           </br>
           </br>
           <input type = "button" onclick = "question1()" name = "question1" value = "Submit"/>
           <br/>
           <br/>
        </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for this clean solution. But beware. this does not work in IE7 http://caniuse.com/queryselector (though, IE7 is used in <1% worldwide http://theie7countdown.com/educate-others)

Answer (score 0):

1. You never define `quiz` so when you attempt to assign a value to `quiz.question1.value`, the code throws an error
2. Your `if` statement is testing to see if a string is a true value, which it always will be. You have too many quotes.

Answer (score 0):

1. For a first thing, you are missing a form element

   < form name="quiz" >
     ...
   < /form >

This needs to be present for your JavaScript code to work.

1. `name` attributes for `radio buttons` and the `submit button` need to be different.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute for radio buttons and the submit button should not be same I guess.
Try changing `name` attribute of submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed your issue by using a hidden field. Good effort for a beginner. But, this is not the best way to do it. Anyway, keep up the good work. You'll get there.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Algebra Reviewer </title>
    <style type="text/css">
    h2
    {
    color: white;
    font-family: verdana;
    text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    }
    table
    {
    font-family:verdana;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function question1()
    {
    if (document.getElementById('question1Answer').value =='d')
    {
    alert ("That's the correct answer!");
    } 
    else
    {
    alert ("Oops! try again!");
    document.getElementById('question1Answer').value =''
    }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </br>
    <h2>
    Here are 10 items for you to answer. You might need scratch paper- so get one before taking this reviewer.
    </h2>
    </br>
    </br>
    <center>
    <table border="0" bgcolor="tan">
    <tr> <td>
    <ol>
    <li> What is the equation of the line passing through point (3,8) and parallel to the line x - 3y = 5 ? </li>
    </br>
    </br> 
    <input type = "radio" name = "question1" onclick = "document.getElementById('question1Answer').value ='a'"/> y = 1/3 x + 5
    </br>
    <input type = "radio" name = "question1" onclick = "document.getElementById('question1Answer').value ='b'"/> y = 3x + 7
    </br>
    <input type = "radio" name = "question1" onclick = "document.getElementById('question1Answer').value ='c'"/> y = 3/5 x + 3
    </br>
    <input type = "radio" name = "question1" onclick = "document.getElementById('question1Answer').value ='d'"/> y = 1/3 x + 7
    </br>
    </br>
    <input type = "hidden" id = "question1Answer" value = ""/>
    <input type = "button" onclick = "question1()" name = "question1" value = "Submit"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    </td> </tr> </table> </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```